# Oracle dbms_crypto messing up data during encryption?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, encryption, plsql

I have a requirement to send an xml payload with some parts being encrypted. Here's a sample format.

```
<xml>
<events>
 <create>
  <person_id/>
  <name/>
  <encrypted_data>64b6fcb391380a0a67b07844b46f9544
e7def8df78c6d7e68b79de62fe5627f9
cb30b3d15b0905f94538475bd681b113
  </encrypted_data>
 </create>
</events>
```

For reference, the decrypted format of the encrypted_data is:

```
<content>
 <date_of_birth/>
 <sex/>
 <address/>
 <email/>
 <phone/>
... etc
</content>
```

So I created the following wrapper package for encryption.

```
 create or replace package body APPS.xxhr_crypto
 is
  function encrypt ( src in clob
      , typ in binary_integer
      , key in raw
      , iv in raw default null ) return blob
  is
    l_enc blob;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary ( l_enc, true );
    dbms_crypto.encrypt (
     dst => l_enc
     , src => src
     , typ => typ
     , key => key
     , iv => iv
    );

    return ( l_enc );
  end;

  function decrypt ( src in blob
      , typ in binary_integer
      , key in raw
      , iv in raw default null ) return clob
  is
    l_dec clob;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary ( l_dec, true );
    dbms_crypto.decrypt (
     dst => l_dec
     , src => src
     , typ => typ
     , key => key
     , iv => iv
    );
    return l_dec;
  end;

 end;
```

Then I also created a package for generating the payload using dbms_xmlgen. Then a function that basically generates a query into an xml clob which I then encrypt in the main procedure that generates the main payload.

```
 create or replace package body APPS.xxhr_publisher
 as
  l_nls_date_format2 nls_session_parameters.parameter%type := 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"';

  function get_emp_sensitive_data_as_xml ( p_person_id in number ) return xmltype
  is
    l_xml xmltype;
    l_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
  begin
    l_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('select * from xxhr_emp_sensitive_pub_v where "personId" = :person_id');

    dbms_xmlgen.setbindvalue(l_ctx, 'person_id', p_person_id);
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(l_ctx, 'content');
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(l_ctx, '');
    l_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype (l_ctx);
    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(l_ctx);

    return l_xml;
  end;

  procedure publish_emp_delta ( errbuff   out varchar2
         , retcode   out number
         , p_event_date in  varchar2
         , p_from_lastname in  varchar2
         , p_to_lastname in  varchar2 )
  is
    l_create xmltype;
    l_payload clob;
    l_create_ctx  dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
    l_response clob;
  begin
    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''' || l_nls_date_format2 || '''';
    l_create_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(
   q'~select a.*
           , xxhr_crypto.encrypt ( ( xxhr_publisher.get_emp_sensitive_data_as_xml (a."personId") ), 4356, 'SECRET_KEY' ) as "_encryptedData"

        from xxhr_employees_pub_v a
       where ( ( fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:event_date) is not null and a."_eventType" = 'create' ) or fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:event_date) is null )
         and lower(a."lastName") between lower(nvl(:from_last_name,a."lastName")) and lower(nvl(:to_last_name,a."lastName"))
         and trunc(a."_eventDate") = nvl(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:event_date),trunc(a."_eventDate"))~');

    dbms_xmlgen.setbindvalue(l_create_ctx,'from_last_name',p_from_lastname );
    dbms_xmlgen.setbindvalue(l_create_ctx,'to_last_name',p_to_lastname );
    dbms_xmlgen.setbindvalue(l_create_ctx,'event_date',p_event_date);
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(l_create_ctx, '');
    dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(l_create_ctx, 'create');

    select xmlserialize ( content ( deletexml ( xmlelement ( "payload", xmlelement ( "correlationId", fnd_global.conc_request_id )
                                                                      , xmlelement ( "initialLoad", nvl2(p_event_date,'false','true') )
                                                                      , xmlelement ( "events", ( select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(l_create_ctx) from dual ) )
             )
          , '/payload/events/*/_eventType' ) ) as clob indent size = 4
       )
      into l_payload
      from dual;  

    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(l_create_ctx);   
  end;  
 end;
```

<strike>When we generate xml payload for many employees, somewhere in the middle, a record will have when some special characters when decrypting the encrypted data.</strike> 
When we generate xml payload for many employees, a particular record will have some special characters when decrypting the encrypted data and it's the same employee every run as long as parameters are the same.

Something like:

```
<xml>
<events>
 <create>
  <person_id>1</person_id>
  <name>Name</name>
  <encrypted_data>
   <content>
    <date_of_birth>1967-09-14T00:00:00Z</date_of_birth>
    <address>ADDRESS LINE 1 ADDRESS LINE 2 ADDRESS LINE 3</address>
    ¿D(¿¿¿4¿M¿¿)M¿¿*¿¿~MZ¿y.œ¿¿¿¿¿¿
   </content>
  </encrypted_data>
 </create>
</events>
```

However, when we try to generate xml payload for this particular employee, it work's fine.

I did some test by removing the encryption part on the query and everything was ok. No special characters in the data.

My hunch is that the encryption procedure xxhr_crypto.encrypt is the culprit since I am not closing/freeing the temporary lob? How do I do this btw, since it is used in a SQL statement, I can't close or free it before returning it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does 'somewhere in the middle' mean it might be a different record each time, not always the same employee? You haven't shown how the payload is sent/received, or decrypted. My guess would be that the transmission is splitting the payload CLOB into chunks, and that process is losing bytes; but then sometimes decryption would corrupt like this, sometimes other parts would be wrong (though maybe less obviously), and sometimes decryption would throw an exception. If it is a single employee, what happens if you encrypt and decrypt just that content locally; or decrypt just that at the other end?

Comment: I'm sorry, I double checked and noticed that it is the same employee every time if running the same parameters. Actually I'm not sending the payload yet. I'm doing the decryption myself manually thru sql dev. If running for a single employee and using the same employee (employee data with issue), it's working fine.